# How to use a function in the middle of an equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I'm reading up on some electrical engineering and have been presented with an expression which I'm unfamiliar with. I've taken College Algebra and I am familiar with the idea of a function in the sense of slope intercept form $f(x) = mx+b$, however this formula appears to have it in the middle of the equation.

*Formula for determining current as a function of time*
$$
q(t)=\int_{t_0}^t i(t) dt + q(t_0)
$$

$q(t)$ is charge in Columbus over time in seconds. $t_0$ is some initial time at which a charge is known. $i(t)$ is the current measured in amperes.

I'm assuming $q(t)$ could be understood as a function, however that function like symbol in the middle is throwing me off. Ideally, it would be awesome if someone could tell me how to evaluate this expression. However I might be able to just settle for someone telling me what that mid equation function is even called so I can research and find out how to use it on my own.

Comment: Do you mean $\int$, the integral symbol?

Comment: $i(t)$ should be understood as a function itself

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC it would seem that yes, that is what I'm referring to. But in addition to that how would you handle $i(t)$ as a function when it's in the middle of the equation and not what is being solved for. Algebraically? If so what would the opposite operation of a function be?

Comment: @Patricio our algebra professor said to just treat any $f(x)$ as basically a single variable term, so then for slope intercept we could consider the $f(x)$ to be the same as $y$. Does this teaching hold true for this expression?

Comment: there is a abuse of notation in the integral, only the upper limit of integration should be a parameter. it should be written $$\int_{t_0}^t i(s)ds,$$ where s is a mute variable.

Comment: about how you can evaluate the expression, i suggest you to look for basic integration theory on some calculus book, it all depends on $i$. for example, if $i(t)$ is constant, then $\int_{t_{0}}^ti(s)ds=i(t_0)(t-t_0).$

Comment: @Alan yeah I'm already on Khan Academy trying to figure out where to start. If I'm correct the integral is used to figure the area under the line drawn by a function? Or am I completely off and need to keep researching?

Comment: yes, if the function is positive, you can interpret the integral as the area under the graph.

Comment: The $\int$ symbol is (as previously mention) an integral symbol. This integral thing is studied in Calculus, so if you've never seen this I suggest you study the basics of this first. In addition, you mention that you understand functions "in the sense of slope-intercept form", but this is just one very specific type of function and you'll need to understand what a function is in general before learning Calculus. I suggest you get a firm understanding of these concepts before jumping into college engineering books.

Comment: @Alan and so then if the function is negative, it would be the area above the graph? Also, could you please put this in an answer so I can give you credit for answering the question?

Comment: Wasn't calculus a prerequisite for the course?

Comment: @Kirkland When the function is negative, it's *minus* the area above the graph.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich it's not a class. I gave up on the Florida education system a long time ago. Being the grandson and nephew of two MIT grads, and nephew of two other Yale Docs, I decided reading and researching on my own was better than what Florida could provide me with so I've gone that way. It's worked very well for myself and my career so far. Basically everyone in my family has gotten to the point where we don't see what most schools offer that just reading can't. Highly opinionated, yes, but our $.02.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich case in point my neighbor has a masters degree in education from UF and also could not make heads or tails of the afore mentioned expression.

Comment: To be fair to your neighbor, there is almost zero reason for someone working in education to have been exposed to this. I'm sure my local baker can't re-gap spark plugs, nor can my mechanic make a good pâte à choux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, the symbol  in your expression is the [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral), and you should learn how to evaluate it for a large class of elementary functions in a first semester of calculus. For instance,
$$
\int_{t_0}^ti(s)ds=i_0(t-t_0)
$$
if $i$ is constant equal to $i_0$ and
$$
\int_{t_0}^ti(s)ds=\frac{m(t^2-t_0^2)}{2}+b(t-t_0),
$$
if $i(t)=mt+b$.

Answer (score 1):

You've already accepted an answer, but I'm going to give you a suggestion anyways: If you're doing EE, don't ask mathematicians about calculus, ask physicists. Mathematicians do calc with full generality, which you will never need, and physicists take shortcuts and make simplifying assumptions which you will find useful. I don't have a specific book to suggest, but if you can find "Calculus for Physicists", try that first.

Now, as for functions - with my physicist's hat on, I'd say "Any time we have a quantity that changes with time, there is a function for that quantity. There will frequently be more than one quantity/function in a given situation. We will find very general rules that relate these functions to each other."

Remember, when you had a rule that related two variables to each other, like say $2x +3y =8$, sometimes you learned more about $y$ and solved for $x$, sometimes you learned more about $x$ and solved for $y$, and sometimes you learned another fact relating $x$ and $y$ to each other, and that helped you find both $x$ and $y$. Well, now you're going to be doing that for multiple functions, instead of multiple variables. And "integrals" (and "derivatives") are going to be a way that different functions can relate to each other. (It's pretty cool, to be honest.)

Hopefully, your calculus-for-physicists book will quickly move on from the "area under a curve" understanding of an integral (that mathematicians like to advocate), and use the "add up many small quantities" model. (BTW, $\int$ is a stylized "S", for "sum".) So for your equation, where $q(t)$ is the charge on a capacitor at time $t$, and $i(t)$ is the current flowing into the capacitor at time $t$, the equation just says "To find the charge on it at time t, $q(t)$, start with the initial charge, $q(t_0)$, and add up ($\int$) all the current flowing in, $i(s)$, and do this as the time runs from $t_0$ to $t$, ($\int_{t_0}^t$). Good luck!

Comment: Loving the (assuming) unintentional reference to Aristotle's Dialectician vs Physicist vs Mathematician reference Ala De Anima. And I've been gathering that there is a lot of multidimensional analysis of measurements in EE as there is in physics and chemistry, being they all collide so often. So far as the it's cool comment, I agree after the Khan Academy video. I've never thought of the area of a curve being useful before, can't wait to get my ALEKS and textbook going. And thanks! You rock!

Comment: Glad you liked it. I've read none of the classics of philosophy, so any bits of _De Anima_ that shine through must have been gleaned from one my teachers who had been influenced by it. And while the area under a curve analogy is nicely general (once you're willing to let the y-axis denote "calories" and the x-axis denote "degrees Kelvin"), and reflects calculus' historical roots in classical area finding problems, the "quantities changing over time" interpretation is really really good for doing physics/chem/engineering, so why not go with that?

Comment: Think I found the textbook https://www.pearson.com/store/p/calculus-for-scientists-and-engineers-early-transcendentals/P100001785735/9780321849212?tab=overview

Comment: Oh, I think I was unclear. There's not a specific text entitled "Calculus for Physicists" that I had in mind (and that one doesn't seem particularly spot-on, from what little the web site says). I meant that you should find a text that introduces calculus with an eye towards being useful for physicist (and engineers, etc.). I'm sure there are more than a few out there - maybe ask at the physics, or EE, stack exchanges?

Comment: No, I got that part. Was looking for calculus texts to be able to go through and stumbled upon that and wondered if it would cover what you were trying to get at in the response, that's all. Thanks for looking into it however!